# Getting and setting pillar values with saltstack python api

Tags: python, api, salt-stack

I am writing some code that integrates with saltstack. I have been able to get the pillar values into a dictionary by using the following:

```
import salt.client
caller = salt.client.Caller()
data = caller.function('pillar.items')
```

However, I have had a hard time finding a way to set the data once I change it in python.

Do you know of a way to set specific pillar values via the saltstack python api?

Comment: Pillar data is static data owned and distributed by the master.  It cannot be changed by a minion/client

Comment: I really hate that this is called as a function and not as it's own method.  If anyone finds a method for this I'd love to see it posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you both donkopotamus and mafrosis. You both added valuable information.

In this case, in order to modify the pillar variables, I will have to modify the variables in the static salt script files. Then I will be able to use them on the salt minions.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set pillar values from the API, however you can write grains:

```
# setting a minion's grain
client = salt.client.LocalClient()
client.cmd('minion_01', 'grains.setval', ('hostname', 'minion_01.example.com'))
```